# How to use jquery with Jtable's custom input and display()?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-jtable

display()

```
   hehe:{
   display: function (data) {
   $t='<button id="tow"></button>';
   return $t;   
   }
```

input()

```
empid:{
input: function (data) {
if (data.record) {
return '<input type="text" id="empid"/>';    }}
```

`$("#tow").click` and `$("#empid").click`  doesn't work .Bind click event before return does't work too.

I can do it like this.

```
onclick="myfunc(this)"
```

But I still need jquery.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need to use `event` [delegation technique](http://api.jquery.com/on/) as follows:

```
$(document).on("click", "#tow", function(){
   //do something here
});

$(document).on("click", "#empid", function(){
   //do something here
});
```